# Working with Python nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I've got a dictionary (teamDictionary) that is seeded with names, teams, and statuses of team members:

```
teamDictionary = {
    1: {'name': 'Bob', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
    2: {'name': 'George', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'},
    3: {'name': 'Sam', 'team': 'B', 'status': 'Travel'},
    4: {'name': 'Phil', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
    5: {'name': 'Georgia', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}
}
```

How can I query the dictionary of dictionaries so that I can get the names of:

- All team members from Team A that are out on Leave, or
- All team members from Team B that are in a Travel status, or
- All team members from Team C that are in Training

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I've tried if statements - `if teamDictionary['team'] == "A" and teamDictionary['status'] == 'Leave' : statusList = teamDictionary['name']`

Comment: ...an numerous other variations, but I keep getting errors indicating that dictionaries are unhashable.

Comment: Willem, I'm not sure what I did to deserve your angst... You down voted my question right off the bat (which flies right in the face of the comments on your profile, BTW), and then you delete your response because it's not the one I opted to use? I learned from my interaction with you - my future posts will be better and include more content on what I've tried; so, thanks for that.

Comment: I did not dv'ed your post... As written on the profile page, I usually comment first what should be improved.

Comment: My apologies. I know better than to jump to conclusions. Guess I'd better practice it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think list comprehensions with the conditions you want would look clean:

```
team_A_on_leave = [player['name'] for player in teamDictionary.values()
                   if player['team'] == 'A'
                   and player['status'] == 'leave']
```

The other 2 scenarios would be similar list comprehensions with different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

We can filter the dictionary:

```
keys = filter(lambda x: teamDictionary.get(x).get('team') == 'A' and teamDictionary.get(x).get('status') == 'Leave', teamDictionary)


filtered_a = {k: teamDictionary.get(k) for k in keys}

{1: {'name': 'Bob', 'status': 'Leave', 'team': 'A'},
 4: {'name': 'Phil', 'status': 'Leave', 'team': 'A'}}
```

You would just change the conditions based on the values you want to check for in the inner dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry - I've got to catch myself up on the lambda thing; I'm new and just not quite there yet. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
teamDictionary = {
1: {'name': 'Bob', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
2: {'name': 'George', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'},
3: {'name': 'Sam', 'team': 'B', 'status': 'Travel'},
4: {'name': 'Phil', 'team': 'A', 'status': 'Leave'},
5: {'name': 'Georgia', 'team': 'C', 'status': 'Training'}
}

a_leave = [b['name'] for a, b in teamDictionary.items() if b['team'] == 'A' and b['status'] == 'Leave']

b_travel = [b['name'] for a, b in teamDictionary.items() if b['team'] == 'B' and b['status'] == 'Travel']

c_training = [b['name'] for a, b in teamDictionary.items() if b['team'] == 'C' and b['status'] == "Training']
```